# How to open a fancybox clean window?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to use a clean window for fancybox, meaning without their custom background and Close button.

can someone guide me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't do that then you  wont be using a fancybox, You should  develop your own modal popup.

Something like on click of an element.

```
$("body").empty().append('<div class="yourpopupwindow">Content Will be here</div>');
```

Comment: ok, there is bpopup, also nice component in jquery, I thought the it's possible with fancybox also, but thanks! :)